# Creating distribution with repackaged spring boot jar using gradle application plugin

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

Is there any way to configure gradle's [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to include only repackaged spring boot jar (by [boot gradle plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)) and other resources (e.g. startup scripts) without other dependencies jars (as they already repackaged by boot gradle plugin)?

Comment: Basically, yes it's possible. Provide an example.

Comment: @Opal, so now, after executing `gradle build` I have an repackaged jar at `build/libs` and tar/zip at `buid/distributions` with all the dependencies.
I just want to have only repackaged jar in tar/zip without unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: Isn't it the case that boot gradle plugin generates the artifact that application plugin generates and you have duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

With spring-boot-gradle-plugin,here is a build.gradle example:

```
ext {
    mainClassName = 'com.x.x'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.x.x'
    layout = 'ZIP'
}

task generateExecutableJar(type: Jar) {
    appendix = 'boot'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task repackage(type: BootRepackage, dependsOn: generateExecutableJar) {
    executable = true
    customConfiguration = 'customDependencies'
    withJarTask = generateExecutableJar
}

configurations {
    customDependencies
}
```